# (Socket) Conexão Cliente e Servidor - como obter retorno do Cmd-> Cliente (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, socket, cliente-servidor

Eu quero executar um comando no Cmd do cliente e retorna os valores pro servidor.
Já Consegui Executar o comando no Cmd do cliente... Agora como faço para retorna os valores pro servidor?

O Servidor:

```
import socket
import os


Host = "127.0.0.1" #str(input("Host: "))
Door = 8291        #int(input("Door: "))

conexao = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

conexao.bind((Host,Door))
conexao.listen(2)

c, e = conexao.accept()

while True:

    os.system('cls')

    print("Connected to : ", e)

    print("\n\n")

    print("|----------------|-------|")
    print("|  Instructions  | Press |")
    print("|----------------|-------|")
    print("|  Send Message  |   1   |")
    print("|----------------|-------|")
    print("|  Send CodeDos  |   2   |")
    print("|----------------|-------|")

    print("\n\n")

    Choice = int(input("I Pick: "))

    os.system("cls")

    if Choice == 1:

        Msg = input("Message:")
        c.send("1".encode('ascii'))
        c.send(Msg.encode('ascii'))


    elif Choice == 2:

        Cod = input("CodeDos:")
        c.send("2".encode('ascii'))
        c.send(Cod.encode('ascii'))


    else:

        print("Faill")
        os.system('pause')
```

O cliente:

```
import socket
import os


Host = "127.0.0.1" #str(input("Host: "))
Door = 8291        #int(input("Door: "))

conexao = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

conexao.connect((Host,Door))

while True:

    info = conexao.recv(1024)

    if info.decode('ascii') == "1":   # If Choice == 1 (Message) Do:

        info = conexao.recv(1024)

        info = info.decode('ascii')

        print(info)

    elif info.decode('ascii') == "2": # If Choice == 2 (CodeDos) Do:

        info = conexao.recv(1024)

        info = info.decode('ascii')

        os.system(info)
```

Comment: No seu 'cliente' você usou apenas o recebimendo com "recv", mas, não enviou novamente para dar um retorno! Pode-se implementar o envio no final do "while" que irá retornar!

Answer (score -1):

Perfeito, já está fazendo a conversa entre servidor e cliente, utilize no cliente a biblioteca **subprocess**

*Nota: Estou utilizando o Windows11, por isso utilizei o encoding **cp850**, pois é como o CMD do windows retorna.

```
import subprocess
command_output = subprocess.run("ipconfig", capture_output = True, encoding='cp850').stdout
print(command_output)
```

No seu caso agora amigo, basta ajustar sua estrutura, abaixo só a parte que eu modifiquei.

**Cliente**

```
import subprocess

...

elif info.decode('ascii') == "2": # If Choice == 2 (CodeDos) Do:
    info = conexao.recv(1024)
    info = info.decode('ascii')
    command_output = subprocess.run(info, capture_output = True, encoding='cp850').stdout
    conexao.send(command_output.encode('ascii'))
```

**Servidor**

```
elif Choice == 2:

    Cod = input("CodeDos:")
    c.send("2".encode('ascii'))
    c.send(Cod.encode('ascii'))
    command_return = c.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
    print(command_return)
```